# Return a filter within an arrayformula based on specific conditions

Tags: filter, google-sheets, formula, array-formulas

I have found other questions about using filters in array formulas, but I haven't been able to identify an answer that addresses my current need.

Basically, I have a table of data that report weekly job activity and changes daily.  So I need an array formula that will expand with it.  For each row, I need the formula to return all employees that used that same project number.

I've tried using the filter, with an indirect inside of it to control how the arrays are managed, but it's still only sampling the first cell of the array to return the data.

Here's the working formula that can be copied into each cell (undesired):

```
=if(B4=D4,join(", ",unique(filter(B$4:B,C$4:C=C4))),)
```

Here's my attempt at the arrayformula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(if(isblank(A4:A), , if(B4:B = D4:D, join(", ", unique(filter(B4:B, C4:C = indirect("C"&row(C4:C)) ))), )))
```

I am starting to suspect that query might be able to do this for me, but I've never used query language, and before I invest the time into learning it for this one function, I thought I'd see if someone has a more immediate answer.

Here's the link to the sample document: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1F98jpuIroCoHhSYxF7ikMv4h5QAcCiyKS6-3VKBl9K0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you change permissions on the sheet so that other people can access it plz?

Comment: @TomSharpe, sorry I thought I had.  You should be able to access it now.

Comment: @TomSharpe, were you able to access the sheet?

Comment: Yes (thank you), but sadly I haven't been able to come up with an answer.